# Is it possible to create two-tone crease/color effect with CSS only

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a creased button effect using CSS to achieve something like this image (not including the white icon in the center):

[image]

I think there's a very faint white shadow/glow to the left of center, on the lighter side, and there's a faint dark shadow or something to the right of center, on the dark side.

I've tried it using a multi-stop gradient, and the two-tone color effect is simple enough, but those white/dark shadows could be a problem.

Comment: Would a gradient work in your case?

Comment: Yeah a gradient is fine, but as I said, I can only get the basic two-tone effect. It's the very subtle white/dark shadows at the center that I can't get.

Comment: I don't know if we are referring to the same thing but this looks more like a shadow or something on the "marker" shape than the background/gradient.

Comment: If you blow it up really big, you can see a faint white glow along the left crease, and a dark glow or line on the right crease. It's very subtle but I think it makes a difference. This is the part I can't replicate.

Comment: I think everybody have missed the point. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7dmc9tcu/) kind of what you need @RTF?

Comment: @Harry yeah that's great. It looks rough at that size, but made smaller it turns out nice. I'd love to get some kind of slight blur on those lines in the center though.

Comment: Maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1499/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is with a gradient. Note, this solution is completely scaleable due to use of percent.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#34495e+0,3f4c6b+50,34495e+50,2c3e50+50,2c3e50+100 */
  background: #34495e;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #34495e 0%, #3f4c6b 50%, #34495e 50%, #2c3e50 50%, #2c3e50 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #34495e 0%, #3f4c6b 50%, #34495e 50%, #2c3e50 50%, #2c3e50 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #34495e 0%, #3f4c6b 50%, #34495e 50%, #2c3e50 50%, #2c3e50 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#34495e', endColorstr='#2c3e50', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty decent. I wonder if I can stick some more gradients between the two, at the center, to get the dark line along the right of the crease/edge. Is there a limit to the number of stops on a gradient?

Comment: No, there isn't any limit. I left comments in my gradient snippet, which includes a link to edit the gradient. You can use that to further experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution, using thick rounded borders

```css
div {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 70px solid #5c6a8f;
  border-right: 70px solid #53618c;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Clever, but not scaleable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use after selector to create a half circle and display it over the circle

```css
.icon{
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  border-radius:50%
}
.icon:before{
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50px;

 }
```

```html
<div class="icon"><div>
```